# LG knock to unlock phone

Tags: android, locking, screen, tap, unlock

I want to create an app to unlock phone after a custom series of taps that the user define it in the app just like the LG tap to unlock option,can anybody tell me how to do it.

Comment: "how to do it" -- how to do *what*? Please tell us what you have tried and what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: I have been searching the web for a code that i can use to keep the touch screen on while the display is off but i can't find anything,i want to keep the touch screen on so that when the user tap the screen with his secret lock defined in app it unlocks the screen,so can u tell me how to keep the touch screen on while the display is off?

Comment: That is not possible in general. Some specialized hardware may support this, but probably not at the level that developers can control.